# How to restrict expression output to 2 decimal places in Watson Conversation?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have the following expression working correctly in a dialog node in Watson Conversation where the expression is used in a response to a user:

```
<? ($total_balance * $acceptable_offer) ?>
```

I need to restrict the output to 2 decimal places. I tried appending toFixed(2) to  the expression in the following format but it did not work:

```
<? ($total_balance * $acceptable_offer).toFixed(2) ?>
```

How can I edit the expression so that the result displays correctly with only 2 digits?

Answer (score 1):

Simply Use:

```
<? T(Math).round($total_balance * $acceptable_offer * 100.00)/100.00?>
```

T(Math) is a new feature in Watson conversation to perform simple maths operations.